# SSH configuration is not found in Running-config in packet tracer

Tags: cisco, switching, ssh

I opened up Packet tracer and configured SSH on a switch (2960) and logged to that switch from a PC. SSH was working. But when I see the running config, no ssh or crypto key configurations could be found in the running config. All the user name + passwords, domain name, Host name could be found.

Is that a problem only in packet tracer? If we configured SSH on a real switch / router, could we be able to view SSH configurations on running - Config ?

Comment: Packet Tracer is pretty bare-bones, [GNS3](http://www.gns3.net/) is probably the most realistic switch/router emulation platform.  Your crypto keys should be present in your `running-config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can't confirm if it's a problem in packet tracer but in my real 2960 running-config  I have all the information needed.